# Get Schema using collection name mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Lets say I have a collection "employees" in mongodb.now i want to get the
Schema of that collection using "mongoose".Can I do that? I want to have the
schema object from the collection name.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

public getMappers(collectionName): Schema {
  let schema = mongoose.model(collectionName).schema;
  return schema ;
}
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Let me explain why? NoSQL DBs are known for the flexibility of the unknown data fields. One document can have a different set of fields from another sibling document. Due to this, a tool can not determine all the fields in your schema (and ponder that fields can be added later as well). However, You can get a superset of fields by looking at all the documents in your collections and creating a schema out of it.

Mongo compass has a schema tab where you can analyze and use the collection menu to export schema JSON. See below:
[image: Compass tabs and collection menu]

You will still need to do a lot of manipulation to create schema out of this JSON, and this JSON isn't meant for creating schema but to understand the kind of data your collection has. e.g. How many docs have this particular field? How many unique values are there for a particular field(cardinality) etc?

Edit 1: I found that the analyzer runs on a subset of docs only not the full collection. We might miss some fields due to that. Read more [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/schema/)